# Bootstrap 4 float property not working with SVG elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get my svg to `float:right;` and `float:left;` in the following **[codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/PoomzLO)**? I am using the `float-right` and `float-left` **[Bootstrap 4 utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)**. But it doesn't work on my `<div>` elements. I'm using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) to create two bar charts and place them side by side.

Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id="barchart"></div>
    <div class="col-6 float-right" id="barchart2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't use floats as far as I know. It's a flexbox based library. I think you *might* be looking for `justify-content:space-between`.

Comment: I am following the bootstrap documentation that uses float. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Paulie_D. I found the following and it worked. "d-flex justify-content-end"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float I used something similar to what Paulie_D suggested.

```
d-flex justify-content-end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `float-right` class to the parent element which is already applied the entire `col-6`.

You need to create a child div and apply the `float-right` and add your `id`s for the bar chart.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="float-left" id="barchart"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="float-right" id="barchart2"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```